# Add if row contains a string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Without the use of macros or anything fancy, is it possible to write an excel formula that would add up Col-1 rows that correspond to Col-2 rows having the string 'st'?

```
+----+-------+-------+
+ #  + Col-1 + Col-2 +
+----+ ------+-------+
+ 1  +  1    + an st +
+ 2  +  2    + f st  +
+ 3  +  1    + st fr +
+ 4  +  1    + bd bd +
+----+-------+-------+
```

So in this example, it should add up rows 1,2 and 3 and return 1+2+1 = 4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way. Use this: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("st",B1:B4))*A1:A4)`

Comment: +1, i would just use `ISNUMBER()` instead of `NOT(ISERR())`

Comment: integrated suggestion. I like it

Answer (score 1):

Why do we not just use:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B4,"*st*",A1:A4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd introduce a third column. The values of the third column will be the one of the first if the second contains the string, 0 otherwise.

Summing up the values in the third column will return the result you want.

If you don't like to display or print the column you introduce you should hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first row is in Row 1, starting at column a, you can add another column to the right which checks for each, using this formula:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("st", C1)), B1, 0)

That should return 1, 2, 1, 0 respectively for your rows.

Sum that column for the total.

Comment: Or use nutsch's solution - it's more elegant ;-)

Comment: Actually this solution also works in google docs spreadsheets